# Can I safely supress integer signedness conversion compiler warnings for "common" projects?

Tags: ios, objective-c, type-conversion, compiler-warnings, signed

I have a legacy project that was working fine in iOS 5, 6, and 7. Not sure which Xcode started it, but I'm seeing a lot of "comparison of integers of different signs int and NSUInteger (aka unsigned int)" warnings.

Code like the below causes such warnings:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < names.count ; i++) // warning here
    {
        [self.images addObject:[NSNull null]];
    }
 for (NSString* name in names)
    {
        int index = [names indexOfObject:name];// warning here
    }
```

I completely understand the implication of this warning if I'm doing some science project or am building a calculator and am working with truly large integers, to the point where signedness would start to matter.

I'm looking at ~400 warnings in a project, of which good 200 are about sign conversion. I personally don't want to go back and add 200 different casts, as it's fugly and makes the code harder to read.

But **for common cases: table view cell indexes, loops, array counts of less than 1000, etc - can I suppress such warnings and be okay?** Am I likely to stumble on some obscure sign conversion bug in a "typical", non-scientific, non-math-heavy iOS project?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The better answer is to use the correct data type. Do not use `int` when working with collection counts and indexes. Look at the documentation. See that `NSArray count` is an `NSUInteger`. `NSArray indexOfObject:` is also `NSUInteger`.

The simple solution is to change your `int` variables to the matching type of `NSUInteger`.

Doing this avoids all kinds of possible issues and warnings and makes your code more correct.

```
for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < names.count ; i++)
{
    [self.images addObject:[NSNull null]];
}

for (NSString* name in names)
{
    NSUInteger index = [names indexOfObject:name];
}
```

Comment: It's a simple solution to state, but if you're working with millions of lines of code, it's not exactly a simple solution to implement.

Comment: @IanMacDonald Your millions of lines of code only has hundreds (at most) uses of `int` to change. It's not really a big issue for most projects.

Comment: Find and replace works well, especial now that there's a preview button which shows the difference. There is very little reason to use int so no harm removing them all.

Comment: One slightly annoying area where you'll still have to cast is table views - for example, `[NSArray -count]` returns an `NSUInteger`, but `numberOfSectionsInTableView:` must return an `NSInteger`.

Comment: Yeah, that's why I usually build with -Wno-sign-compare.